# R showing Errors on mac

Tags: r

```
During startup - Warning messages:
1: package ‘utils’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
2: package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'utils', details:
  call: switch(os, Linux = if (file.exists("/etc/os-release")) {
  error: EXPR must be a length 1 vector
```

R console shows these errors when I start it, leading to R studio not working too. I installed R-4.2.1-arm64.pkg from https://cloud.r-project.org/ on my M1 Mac. Even though /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library shows the utils and stats packages, error is still showing.

Comment: remove and reinstall r and see if that helps

Comment: already tried, not working. Seems to be an installation issue acc to my research. But how to fix it 

Comment: @SwapnilDubey Try running `uname -a` on your terminal. It's returning something very funky (= empty) for R to fail like this.

Comment: 'uname -a' runs properly

Comment: OK, then try (again on the terminal): `R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES=NULL Rscript --vanilla -e 'system("uname -a", intern = TRUE)'`

Comment: this shows the errors : 
'During startup - Warning messages:
1: package ‘utils’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
2: package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found'

Comment: @SwapnilDubey Just to check: did you see my edited comment? You need to use `R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES=NULL`. Initially I had accidentally omitted the `NULL` part. I'm asking because `NULL` specifically prevents these packages from being loaded.

Comment: oh yes! The new command doesn't show any errors.

Comment: R is still showing the same errors though

Comment: @SwapnilDubey OK, but what *does* it show? Any output at all? It *should* show the same output as `uname -a`. If it does, could you please also try the following: `R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES=NULL Rscript --no-environ --no-init-file -e 'system("uname -a", intern = TRUE)'`. And lastly, the same command but without `--no-environ`. Do all these produce the same output, or does any of them not produce any output?

Comment: All of them produce the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Run `uname -a`, if it returns more than one line, then you likely need to rename your system into something shorter, until `uname -a` returns on a single line. You can rename your system in terminal using:

sudo scutil --set HostName write_new_short_name

This worked for me on an M1 Ultra Mac Studio